# Materialized view creates quickly with data but cannot refresh

Tags: postgresql, memory, materialized-view

I am working with a database on Amazon RDS and have a specific query which joins about 6 tables on keys. Creating the materialised view with data takes about 3 minutes and behaves as expected with minimal database load, but attempting to refresh the materialized view brings the database down by exhausting the 32GB memory available to the instance in under 5 minutes.

Is there any explanation for this inconsistent behaviour or way to anticipate it to avoid bringing down the database instance?

Comment: Are you using `refresh ... concurrently`?

Comment: No - and the matview has no indexes at all.

Comment: Apologies - I use `refresh materialized view` with no `concurrently`.